# integrating ServiceNow with Chef using amazon SQS

Tags: chef-infra, amazon-sqs, servicenow

I have a use case where ServiceNow creates an SQS topic :

```
sendMessage(
   current.variables.requested_for.u_ad_samaccountname.toString(),
   current.variables.ssh_key.toString()
);

function sendMessage(user_name, ssh_key)
{
   var formatter = null;
   try
   {
       formatter = new SshKeyMessageCreator(user_name, ssh_key);
   }
   catch(e)
   {
       gs.log('DEBUG >>> error: ' + e);
       return;
   }
   var msg = new AwsSqsMessage('https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/465310850895/testqueue2', gs.getProperty('aws.sqs.acctprov.id'), gs.getProperty('aws.sqs.acctprov.key'), formatter.message);
```

and I need to access this message to trigger a cookbook in order to create a user in chef server

I just looked at :

1. https://github.com/FastRobot/chef_aws_demo
2. https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-chef-node-cleanup
3. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/automatically-delete-terminated-instances-in-chef-server-with-aws-lambda-and-cloudwatch-events/

With reference to Josh's demo "Cooking with aws , July 2016" But he is working with cloudwatch alarms instead of SQS

Answer (score 0):

Chef is not an event-based system. There is nothing in Chef that listens for SQS events. You would have to write something for this yourself.